# moving from permissions to optional_permissions: how to handle content_scripts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Originally posted this question here:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/wbSpXvnO10A/nov36skmnQ0J

---

My extension has an optional feature that interacts with the user's gmail tab. We don't want to mention mail.google.com domains at all in the permission confirmation that the user sees when first installing the extension. So I moved that entry out of the manifest's permissions block and into the optional_permissions block. We also needed to use a content script tied to mail.google.com, but defining this in the manifest causes the 'mail.google.com' permission warning that is sppoking some users.

I've tried removing the content_script manifest block and using Programmatic Injection instead as describe here. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi
However scripts injected that way are not content scripts and don't have access to the needed APIs (chrome.tabs, etc)

Is there some way to get the best of both worlds: use optional_permission, AND get the content scripts added to a matching URL, but only if the user has approved the optional permission?

Comment: What's your extension?

Comment: Code injected via tabs.executeScript has exactly the same privileges as content scripts. Content scripts don't have access to most of chrome.* APIs either. Those are available to the background page. You need to request access to the pages you want to inject anyway. Maybe requesting for access to all websites, resulting in "Access your data on all websites" is less scary than mentioning mail.google.com specifically?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could create a background page, and call chrome.tabs.query against your optional origin to get a list of tabs that match that host. You can then call programmatic injection to the content script (chrome.tabs.executeScript). None of these require the "tabs" permission (many "tabs" functions don't require any special permission, and it intelligently lets you query for tabs whose origins match your optional permission)

You could call this every second or so to see if there are any new tabs for which you haven't yet called executeScript.

It would be nice if this were edge-triggered. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=264704

You can actually get it to be mostly edge triggered by using chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener and simply trying to inject every time that is triggered (which will be every time a page loads in any tab, regardless of whether you have permission or not). You'll get a lot of errors in the background script's console when you don't have permission. It will be important to have your content script set a variable like _I_already_executed=true and check for its existence so that you're not injecting multiple times (this event gets triggered several times for each page load)

Comment: In the sake of keeping this answer fresh, this is now possible using `requestContentScript` from `declarativeContent`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-RequestContentScript

Answer (score 1):

Now there's the [`contentScripts.register()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contentScripts/register), which lets you programmatically register content scripts.

```js
browser.contentScripts.register({
    matches: ['https://mail.google.com/*'],
    js: [{file: 'content.js'}]
});
```

This API is only available in Firefox but there's a [Chrome polyfill](https://github.com/fregante/content-scripts-register-polyfill) you can use. The new scripts will work exactly like your regular content scripts in manifest.json.

For a more comprehensive solution you could look into my [`webext-domain-permission-toggle` and `webext-dynamic-content-scripts`](https://github.com/fregante/webext-dynamic-content-scripts/blob/master/how-to-add-github-enterprise-support-to-web-extensions.md) modules, which don't apply directly to your use case but can be helpful to who wants to drop the `<all_urls>` permission and inject content scripts on demand.